# railsでgrapeを使用した場合” Unable to autoload constant API,〜(LoadError)”というエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape

ruby初心者です。
初歩的な質問失礼します。

この記事(http://blog.dakatsuka.jp/2011/05/27/grape.html)を参考にrailsにgrapeをいれてAPIを作成しようとしてますが、

```
/Users/masah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:481:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant API, expected /Users/masah/cospic/lib/api.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

というエラーが出てきてしまいました。

どのように対処すればいいでしょうか。

lib/api.rb

```
module Cospic
  class API < Grape::API
      # APIアクセスに接頭辞を付加
      # ex) http://localhost:3000/api
      prefix "api"

      # APIアクセスにバージョン情報を付加
      # ex) http://localhost:3000/api/v1
      version 'v1', :using => :path

      resource "users" do
        # ex) http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users
        desc "returns all users"
        get do
          User.all
        end
        # ex) OK: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1
        # ex) NG: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/a
        desc "return a user"
        params do
          requires :id, type: Integer
        end
        get ':id' do
          User.find(params[:id])
        end
      end
    end
    end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :layers
  resources :posts
  resources :users
  resources :posts do
   collection do
    get 'tag'
  end
end

 root 'posts#index'

 get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create' 
 get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy' , :as => :logout


  resource :user, only: :destroy do
    get 'retire'
    end
   resources :posts,except: :index do   
  #resources :posts,except: :index do
    resources :likes, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

 #collection do
  #  get 'tag/:tag_name'
  #end
  end

  #match '*path' => 'application#error404', via: :all
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', via: [ :get, :post, :patch ]

end
mount Cospic::API => "/"
```

config/application

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
module Cospic
class Application < Rails::Application

  config.generators do |g|
    g.orm :active_record
    end
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
  end
end
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 同じ質問が本家にありました。[Why am I getting "Unable to autoload constant" with Rails and grape?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319681/why-am-i-getting-unable-to-autoload-constant-with-rails-and-grape)

Comment: ありがとうございます！
解決しました！

Answer (score 2):

### 1行でまとめ

`lib/api.rb`を`lib/cospic/api.rb`に移動するとうまく読み込まれると思います。

#### 定数を参照すると自動で読み込まれるしくみ

元記事の方では以下のように書かれています。

```
# config/initializers/api.rb
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/api"
```

これは明示的に`lib/api.rb`を読み込んでいるので、`lib/api.rb`に書かれた`Cospic::API`はきちんと読み込まれます。

明示的に書かない場合、Railsが定数の名前`Cospic::Api`をもとにそのファイルを読み込もうとします。
`Cospic::Api`と書いた場合、`Cospic`というネームスペースが指定されているので、`autoload_paths`の`cospic`ディレクトリ以下のファイルを読みにいきます。例えば以下のような場所のファイルです。

- `app/models/cospic/api.rb`
- `app/controllers/cospic/api.rb`
- `lib/cospic/api`

なので、`lib/api.rb`を`lib/cospic/api.rb`に移動するとうまく読み込まれると思います。

定数名からどうやってロードするファイルを決めるのか、詳しい仕組みは以下のRails Guideを読んでください。
今回のケースは6.2あたりです。

[Constant Autoloading and Reloading — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/constant_autoloading_and_reloading.html)

#### 余談

アプリケーション固有のコードであるなら`app`以下に置くとよいのではないでしょうか。
他のcontrollerとファイルの置き場所が混ざって気持ちが悪いなら、`app/api`ディレクトリを作って`autoload_paths`に加えれば解決します。

あと`mount Cospic::Api`を書く場所が違っているように見えます。
`mount`書くのは`Rails.application.routes.draw`の中です。

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Cospic::Api
end
```

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます！！